# Unable to align div and a button in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` and a `button`. The button should be placed in the same line as the div. But I am unable to do that. The button is displayed in the next line. How can I do that?
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "
        <div class='data'>
            <p id='theData'>Name</p>
        </div>
    ";
?>
<button class="copyBtn" onclick="copyToClipboard('theData')">Copy Data</button>
```

These are the CSS code given for the data element

```
.data{
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#000000;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    border:2px solid #EF6C00;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.data,.copyBtn{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
.data,
.copyBtn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.data {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #EF6C00;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='data'>
  <p id='theData'>Name</p>
</div>
<button class="copyBtn" onclick="copyToClipboard('theData')">Copy Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='data' style="display: inline-block;">
        <p id='theData'>Name</p>
    </div>
<button class="copyBtn" onclick="copyToClipboard('theData')">Copy Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button in a div and float both divs. Tweak the position of the button with the padding of the div it's in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .data, .buttonWrap {float:left;}
        .buttonWrap {padding:13px 0 0 20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='data'><p id='theData'>Name</p></div>
        <div class="buttonWrap"><button class="copyBtn" onclick="copyToClipboard('theData')">Copy Data</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is this:

```
.data{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#000000;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    border:2px solid #EF6C00;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

adding the `display:inline-block` line to your css' rule you'll get a very simple and scalable solution. And i strongly recommend you stay with this. Other solutions would involve adding extra rules or extra HTML(check the other answers here to good examples of it).